# twitter api. how to leave messages from another webpage?

Tags: api, twitter

i have a website where people can leave comments on some articles. \

what i would like to do is to post those answers on my tweeter page.

is there a way?

thanks

edit1:
i've looked around but i am new at this and i was wondering if anyone has an starter example for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way to do this programmatically, but it depends on the language you plan to use.

Also be warned that if your users leave a lot of comments, you will end up with a lot of tweets. This will most likely hit twitter's update limit (1000 per day, further broken down into a number they don't disclose). Also if you include links you might get reported as spam.

> maybe php, or java script

With php, I recommend you look into [twitteroauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth). JavaScript might get tricky depending on if it's a browser extension, Adobe Air application, or simple JavaScript on a page.

Comment: @Patrioticcow Added my response inline